# How to update column values depending on the outcome of a query in SQL Server Express

Tags: sql, triggers, sql-server-express

I have two tables `Product` and `ProductInventory`. I created a FULL Join and made a query which gives me the `Makeflag` for all the product whose quantity has gone to zero.

How can I manipulate the output so that I can change the values of `Makeflag` to 1 for all the products whose quantity has gone to 0?

Query below is actually affecting all the values for the `Makeflag` not just for the products whose quantity has gone to zero.

What am I doing wrong... Please help!

```
Use AdventureWorks2008R2

Select 
    Quantity, MakeFlag 
from Production.ProductInventory
FULL Join AdventureWorks2008R2.Production.Product
ON ProductInventory.ProductID = Product.ProductID where Quantity = 0

update AdventureWorks2008R2.Production.Product set MakeFlag = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick

```
update AdventureWorks2008R2.Production.Product set MakeFlag = 1 
WHERE ProductID IN (
  SELECT ProductID FROM from Production.ProductInventory where Quantity = 0
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE AdventureWorks2008R2.Production.Product SET MakeFlag = 1
WHERE AdventureWorks2008R2.Production.Product.ProductId IN
(SELECT Product.ProductID from Production.ProductInventory FULL Join AdventureWorks2008R2.Production.Product ON ProductInventory.ProductID = Product.ProductID where Quantity = 0)
```